# error reallocating 2d array using realloc in c

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

I am getting an  error in a huge application that I have when I try to reallocate a 2d int array. Trying to narrow down the problem, I generated a small code only with the reallocations.
ERROR :

```
 a.out: malloc.c:3574: mremap_chunk: Assertion ((size + offset) & (mp_.pagesize-1)) == 0' failed.
```

Aborted.

Relevant code:

```
 int main()    
 {

    int **am=NULL,size=0,ans=0,i;
    char **name=NULL;
    while(ans!=7)
    {
    printf("\n\n\t1. Add a Point \n\n\t2.Exit\n\n\t\t Enter your Choice : ");
    scanf("%d",&ans);
    switch(ans)
    {
            case 1 :
                    name=realloc(name,(size+1)*sizeof(char *));                            
                    name[size]=realloc(name[size],100*sizeof(char));                        

                    printf("\nEnter Name of Point : ");
                    scanf("%s",name[size]);

                    am=realloc(am,(size+1)*sizeof(int *));                          
                    am[size]=realloc(am[size],(size+1)*sizeof(int));                ``

                    if(size > 0 && am==NULL)
                    {
                            printf("Error : Can not Allocate Memory !");
                            break;
                    }
                    for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
                    {
                            if(i!=size)
                            {
                                    am[size][i]=INFINITE;
                                    am[i][size]=INFINITE;
                            }
                            else
                                    am[i][size]=0;
                    }
                    size++;
                    break;
            case 2 :
                    exit(0);

    }
 }

 }
```

Comment: Are you sure the the pointer you are passing to realloc is still pointing to the original allocation or subsequent reallocation? Realloc probably doesn't think you're pointing to a valid allocation anymore.

Comment: Can you suggest the solution of that ....I actually have no idea why it happens? @GoatInTheMachine

Comment: By assigning am[i][size]=999 i am actually initializing the last col which is added to the array by reallocation. and by am[size][i]=999 i am doing the same for the last row added.actually i am not getting what's wrong here.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is here:

```
name=realloc(name,(size+1)*sizeof(char *));                            
name[size]=realloc(name[size],100*sizeof(char));
```

The memory returned by `realloc (NULL,)` is uninitialized. This means that you're passing a random pointer to the second `realloc()`. Use `malloc()` instead.

The same goes for the second pair of `realloc()` calls.

There is another problem here:

```
for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
{
  if(i!=size)
  {
    am[size][i]=INFINITE;
    am[i][size]=INFINITE;
```

You're accessing `am[i][size]` for every `am[i]`, but only the last one will actually have that many elements. The amount allocated will grow through every round of the `while` loop. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: +1 And the same goes for `am` a couple of lines down.

Comment: i did following :                                             name[size]=(char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));                            
am[size]=(int *)malloc((size+1)*sizeof(int));                                                        Still it is giving the same error

Comment: In your `for` loop, you access `am[i][size]`, but you don't have that many elements for all `[am][i]`, because the amount allocated is growing with every round through your `while` loop. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: Actually my logic was to assign 999 to newly added row and col everytime when reallocation occurs.While testing it actually adds that many elements in array. but after 3 or 4 times it is giving an error.

Comment: That's probably when you start to overwrite something important, such as the internal structures used by `malloc()` and `realloc()`.

Comment: By assigning am[i][size]=999 i am actually initializing the last col which is added to the array by reallocation. and by am[size][i]=999 i am doing the same for the last row added.actually i am not getting what's wrong here.?

Comment: `am[0]` is allocated room for 1 `int` on the first round through the `while` loop. With every round, you access one more element (in your `for` loop). After 5 rounds you're accessing `am[0][5]` which clearly doesn't exist. You realloce `am` through every round, but you **also** need to reallocate **every** `am[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what really was required;adding a for loop above reallocation of am[size] to make the square array am[size][size]

Code:

```
 int main()    
 {

    int **am=NULL,size=0,ans=0,i;
    char **name=NULL;
    while(ans!=7)
    {
    printf("\n\n\t1. Add a Point \n\n\t2.Exit\n\n\t\t Enter your Choice : ");
    scanf("%d",&ans);
    switch(ans)
    {
            case 1 :
                    name=realloc(name,(size+1)*sizeof(char *));                            
                    name[size]=realloc(name[size],100*sizeof(char));                        

                    printf("\nEnter Name of Point : ");
                    scanf("%s",name[size]);

                    am=realloc(am,(size+1)*sizeof(int *));                          
                    for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
                            am[i]=realloc(am[i],(size+1)*sizeof(int));                ``

                    if(size > 0 && am==NULL)
                    {
                            printf("Error : Can not Allocate Memory !");
                            break;
                    }
                    for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
                    {
                            if(i!=size)
                            {
                                    am[size][i]=INFINITE;
                                    am[i][size]=INFINITE;
                            }
                            else
                                    am[i][size]=0;
                    }
                    size++;
                    break;
            case 2 :
                    exit(0);

    }
 }

 }
```